# Is it possible to use standalone GORM with Spring Boot but still have controllers in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, grails-orm

I would like to use standalone GORM with Spring Boot but still have the controllers written in Java. Is this possible? If the application class and the controllers are written in Groovy then everything works, but if I write the controllers in Java then the compiler complains that it cannot find the GORM domain classes. I know I could have the controllers as technically Groovy files but written in a Java idiom, but I would like to have the code processed by the Java compiler to avoid the few cases where Java code isn't valid Groovy code or has different semantics.